# MVC build errors when building MVC 5.2.3 project on Windows 7 machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, git, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

Apologies in advance if this is a repeat question, but after much searching I could not find anything about this on the site as of yet.

Our team has run into quite a snag. Our main team works on Windows 8 machines, with VS2013 Premium. We are all running version 4.5.51641 of the of the .NET Framework.

We recently had two people join our team and their computers have Windows 7 installed, with VS 2013 Premium as well as the same version of the .NET Framework.

We use git for source control, which I mention since perhaps it is relevant (something we are forgetting to ignore, perhaps?)

Our issue is that when these team members clone the project, anyone using Windows 8 appears to be able to build it without issue. However, when we attempt to do this on the Windows 7 machines, we get MVC build errors as if it doesn't detect it or could not find it.

**Error example**

> 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition
>   for 'RenderAction' and no extension method 'RenderAction' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Short of doing a clean install of Windows 8 (which is in progress as I type this, for one member) we're scratching our heads here.

Can anyone share some insight as to what may be happening and how we can perhaps resolve it?

Comment: My guess is that it won't build on your new Windows 8 build either. I'd check MVC assembly reference on the project.